# if Statement (VERIFIED)

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to make a code that's verified if someone (1) is checking out his name but it does not really

```
<?php if($usrn['verified'] == 1): { ?>

 <i class="fa fa-check-circle verified verified-sm showTooltip" title="Verified User" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></i>


<?php } endif; ?>

<?php
$usern = protect($_GET['usern']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchasify_users WHERE usern='$usern' OR id='$id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0) { $redirect = $web['url']."not_found"; header("Location: $redirect"); }
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Your syntax is clearly incorrect

Comment: What is the right syntax?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code like this

// suppose $usrn['verified'] == 1;

```
<?php
 $usrn['verified'] =1;
 if($usrn['verified'] == 1) { ?>

 <i class="fa fa-check-circle verified verified-sm showTooltip" title="Verified User" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></i>


<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: <?php
$usern = protect($_GET['usern']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM purchasify_users WHERE usern='$usern' OR id='$id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0) { $redirect = $web['url']."not_found"; header("Location: $redirect"); }
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
?>

Comment: what is this? this is related in this issue?

Comment: What is the structure of that object? You can use a 'var_dump($usern);' to see what is inside of it.

Comment: i have no table so in this case i can not data, but you need to update your value i guess

Comment: or you can send me then print value then i can understand

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam, can you provide teamvieuwer support ;3

Comment: i am stay office so i can not , if you want then skype

Comment: Yeah add me pls "contact@boetdeboer.nl"

Comment: added , i think

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($usrn['verified'] == 1) { ?>

     <i class="fa fa-check-circle verified verified-sm showTooltip" title="Verified User" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></i>

<?php } ?>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two different variants of conditionals here.

**Right**

You can either use:

```
if (condition) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
if (condition):
    // do stuff
endif;
```

**Wrong**

You are doing:

```
if (condition): {
    // do stuff
}
```

this will throw a Syntax Error.

***Further information***

[Official PHP Documentation: Conditionals](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this shortcut

```html
$usrn['verified']=1;
echo ($usrn['verified'] == 1)? '<i class="fa fa-check-circle verified verified-sm showTooltip" title="Verified User" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></i>' : '';
```

echo ($usrn['verified'] == 1)? 'ghbftjfgj' : '';